# How to align my label and input field

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I want my input field "title" to render directly below the radio buttons, but now it is too far to the left. I need the extra `div` because it is a dynamic form, but I want the grid view. How can I accomplish that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href=
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
      textarea {
        height: 600px !important width: 500 px !important
      }
      .inline {display: inline-block;}
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action=
          "http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/upload/ahFkZXZ-bW9udGFvcHJvamVjdHIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICAgLwLDA"
          class="ui form formular" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formular"
          method="post" name="formular">
      <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
        <div class="two wide column">
          <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          <div class="field">
            <span class=
                  "ui two column grid"><label>Category</label></span>
          </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="column field">
          <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          <div class="inline field" id="type_container">
            <span class="ui two column grid"><input name="type" type=
                                                    "radio" value="s"> <label>A</label> <input name="type"
                                                                                               style="margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" value="k">
              <label>B</label></span>
          </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="maintext" id="category_contents" style="display: block;">
        <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
        <div class="row">
          <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          <div class="two wide column inline">
            <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
            <div class="field">
              <span class=
                    "ui two column grid"><label>Title</label></span>
            </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="column field inline">
            <span class="ui two column grid"><input name="title"
                                                    placeholder="Title" type="text"></span>
          </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          <div class="two wide column">
            <span class="ui two column grid"></span>
            <div class="field">
              <span class=
                    "ui two column grid"><label>Text</label></span>
            </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="column field">
            <span class="ui two column grid"><input name="data"
                                                    placeholder="Test" type="text"></span>
          </div><span class="ui two column grid"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to increase the space between the Title label and the Title input field. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't really know for sure if this is what you want, but have you tried adding `padding-right:15px` to `.ui.form .field>label ` ?

Comment: @Maharkus But if I do that, then zooming won't work.

Comment: @Programmer 400: SemanticUI - Also awesome framework It has bunch of options, it my suggestion don't adopted another framework and try to figured it out issue. What you are getting. I will help you out.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq I like semantic-ui and I want this to work. My use case is that the extra div is displayed when an option is chosen, therefore I need the extra div.

Comment: I'm checking your query and I will update you shortly.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq Great answer, thanks! :-) I have now integrated your solution in my larger codebase. It works to create another `ui` div around and then I can control that with my script. I have a website where I use semantic-ui which I think is good. It reduces the code and makes the code easy to read once it works. I'm really glad we could solve this completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had checked your HTML form it has some unwanted columns. Now I have updated the form and I created two demos and I used form elements and grid layout for two columns form.

**Semantic-UI Basic Form:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="example">
   <h4 class="ui header">Semantic UI Form</h4>
   <form class="ui form">
      <div class="field">
         <label>First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <label>Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
   <div class="field">
            <label>Categories</label>    
      </div>
   <div class="field">
    <div class="inline fields">
    <div class="field"> 
     <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency" checked="checked">
        <label>A</label>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
     <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>B</label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
     <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>C</label>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
      <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

**Semantic-UI Two Column Form:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui text container">
  <h4 class="ui header">Semantic UI Form</h4>
  <form class="ui form"> 
 <div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide column ">
   <label>First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve wide column">
   <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide column ">
   <label>Last Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve wide column">
   <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide column ">  
   <div class="field">
    <label>Categories</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve wide column"> 
   <div class="inline fields">   
     <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="frequency" checked="checked">
      <label>A</label>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="frequency">
      <label>B</label>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="frequency">
      <label>C</label>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: With a little work this solved my problem. Now the layout should be responsive. If we had hardcoded the pixels then the design would not be responsive. So I'm very happy with your answer. My case is that selecting an option should expand a sub-category, similar to [this form](https://www.blocket.se/ai/form/0) if you select "lägenheter" from category then the below form will expand. My form is supposed to be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your `label`

```
<label style="padding-right:50px">Title</label>
```

Also you can use `table` in your design to make your page design more efficient.

Comment: Actually "OP" has asked to "Semantic UI" framework(Just like BootStrap) for his project and getting issues related that framework. We couldn't use fixes like that.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Bootstrap - it will take you no more than 30 mins to understand and will make your website page/website layout so easy see - http://getbootstrap.com/

Also, means you website will be mobile and tablet friendly.

1. just add the files to your website -http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ (under first heading Bootstrap CDN).
2. then paste in the relevant form layout you would like (you can tweak these) - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms (under css heading)
3. see the grid layout system - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
4. See all the things you can do just pasting in the bootstrap code: buttons, icons, etc (all listed under components - http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: give me 10 mins and i will build your code - with bootstrap and paste it here so you can see :-)

Answer (score -1):

Re my answer - have made your view using bootstrap as per my steps 1 - 4. Took me 7 mins, not even 10 :-) ..paste the below into an index file to test/see what it looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <form class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Text" id="inputText"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```