# CSS display inline makes two rows instead of one

Tags: css, semantic-ui

What should I use if my layout looks good without the display element, then I must add `display: none` which is set dynamically to `display: block` which destroys my layout. Is there no "normal" display? I have tried `inline` and it doesn't work either. I want to first set it to `display: none` and then I want it to look like it had no or "normal" display property.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">


    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="center jumbotron">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; width: 75%">
           <h4 class="ui header">Semantic UI Form</h4>

                <form  name="formular" class="ui form">
                    <div class="ui grid">
                        <div class="four wide column ">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui grid">
                        <div class="four wide column ">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

             

 <div class="ui grid" id="category_contents">
                        <div class="four wide column ">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <div style="display: inline;" id="categor2y_contents" class="ui grid">
                        <div  class="four wide column ">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>



                <!--    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button> -->
                </form>
            </div>








        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

- Update

The solution was to add an extra  `<div class="ui grid">` but how am I supposed to know that?

Comment: please share the code what you have tried to debug easily

Comment: _“then I must add `display: none` which is set dynamically to `display: block` which destroys my layout”_ — I have no idea, what you’re talking about. Can you [edit] your question and include any code that helps to reproduce this issue and describe it clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add another `ui grid`. I found this solution from another answer [How to align my label and input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440246/how-to-align-my-label-and-input-field)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">


    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="center jumbotron">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; width: 75%">
           <h4 class="ui header">Semantic UI Form</h4>

                <form  name="formular" class="ui form">
                    <div class="ui grid">
                        <div class="four wide column ">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui grid">
                        <div class="four wide column ">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

             

 <div style="display: block;" class="ui grid" id="category_contents">
                       
 <div class="ui grid">
             
                        <div  class="four wide column ">
                            <label>Last N2ame</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twelve wide column">
                            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                

</div>

                <!--    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button> -->
                </form>
            </div>








        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are wanting to revert back to an element's initial state of `display`  after you've overwritten it with `display:none;` correct? If so, simply:

```
#element {
    display: initial;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: Thing is that the initial state is hidden. Now I could fix it if you see my "solution" - not even a hack but plenty of divs.